# How to convert string to dict

Tags: python

I have a string :

```
datalist = "popupWin:'http://www.adachikan.net/index.php/catalog/product/gallery/id/3049/image/1861/', useZoom: 'cloudZoom', smallImage: 'http://www.adachikan.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/315x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/8/187267-875-40.jpg'"
```

And i want to convert this string into Python Dict. I can use split to break the string and form list:

```
datalist.split(',') = ["popupWin:'http://www.adachikan.net/index.php/catalog/product/gallery/id/3049/image/1861/'",
 " useZoom: 'cloudZoom'",
 " smallImage: 'http://www.adachikan.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/315x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/8/187267-875-40.jpg'"]
```

And so on to get the desired result...

I there any easy way to use this `datalist` as a dict like : `datalist['smallImage']` etc..

Comment: Won't *someone* please think of the embedded commas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each item after splitting by ',', by ':'. like so:

```
datadict = {}
for item in datalist.split(','):
    key, value = item.split(':', 1)
    datadict[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

Comment: `datadict['smallImage']
 "'http://www.adachikan.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/315x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/8/187267-875-40.jpg'` can you tell me how to remove extra quotes around the above output

Comment: You forgot t in split at line  `key, value = item.spli(':', 1)` it should be split instead spli

Comment: Got it by using `(datadict['smallImage']).strip("'")`

Comment: to strip out the extra quotes, try `dict[key.strip()] = value.strip(" '")` to strip both the spaces and the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension with `str.split` and `str.strip`:

```
>>> dic = {k.strip(): v.strip().strip("'")  
                     for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in datalist.split(','))}
>>> dic
{'useZoom': 'cloudZoom', 'popupWin': 'http://www.adachikan.net/index.php/catalog/product/gallery/id/3049/image/1861/', 'smallImage': 'http://www.adachikan.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/315x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/8/187267-875-40.jpg'}
>>> dic['smallImage']
'http://www.adachikan.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/315x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/8/187267-875-40.jpg'
```